# execCommand insertHTML inserting multiple times

Tags: contenteditable, execcommand

I am working on a small RTE in a contentEditable DIV. I have attached a keypress event handler to the DIV that monitors when the ENTER key is struck and where the selection is. If it is inside a text node, I am inserting a new line. However, this code is buggy and often inserts 4 newlines instead of one (I have to press undo 4 times to get back to where the cursor was before - that's why I think execCommand is firing multiple times). On the other hand, it sometimes requires TWO strikes of the ENTER key to get a new line inserted.

here is a code snippet of the keypress event handler, once it's determined that the ENTER key has been pressed:

```
if(selection.focusNode.nodeType!=3){ return; }
ev.preventDefault();
var HTML='&#x000A;';
toolbar.target.ownerDocument.execCommand('insertHTML',false,HTML);
```

I want to use execCommand to preserve the browser's undo behavior. I do NOT want to insert a `<br>` as this insertion only happens in a text node and for post-processing purposes, I need \n in the text nodes instead of `<br>`'s or any other block-type tags. I am using the unicode newline character `&#x000A;`. I have tried the carriage return character `&#x000D;` as well with similar results. I can't use `\n` with `insertHTML` because that is not proper HTML.

Anyone have ideas about how to make sure that execCommand runs ONLY once?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out a solution for your problem?

Comment: @nrako: no i did not. I wish I had, but I eventually abandoned the project after multiple frustrations with execCommand. I was watching http://code.google.com/p/rangy/ intently for a while, as Tim was working on a execCommand replacement. Nothing yet, but I remain hopeful.

Comment: Use ppk's [reference implementation](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/) to see what can be done.